# при вводе данных, считывает только одну строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = [str(i) for i in input().split()]
print(f'г. {a[0]}, ул.{a[1]}, д. {a[2]}, кв. {a[3]}')
```

```
 Test input:
=========
  Москва 
  Воздвиженка
  9
  1
```

каждый элемент с новой строки, но вводится за один раз

Answer (score 1):

в конце каждой строке у вас знак перевода строки, который означает нажатие на <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Если вы используете стандартный ввод, то так работать не будет.

##### Что можно сделать

1. Подавать данные в строку

   ```py
   Москва Воздвиженка 9 1
   ```
2. Определить `while` до первой пустой строки

   ```py
   a = []
   while True:
       user_input = input()
       if user_input:
           a.append(user_input)
       else:
           break
   ```

   Здесь вводить можно столько строк сколько надо, до появления первой пустой строки или другими словами нажатие <kbd>Enter</kbd> без введения данных в строку
3. Отказаться от стандартного ввода `input` и хранить и подавать данные из переменной/файла